# Adding multiple markers to Google Maps

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I'm trying to add multiple markers to Google Maps. I am using .NET MVC 4 and I am passing a ViewModel to the View with an array containing all the coordinates. I want to display all these into Google Maps. The array is named latLngCoordinates in the ViewModel.

```
@model Project.Web.ViewModels.ParkingViewModel
```

Code that goes wrong:

```
for (var i = 0; i < @Model.latLngCoordinates.Length; i++) {
            addMarker(@Model.latLngCoordinates[i]);
}
```

Error: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context.

This code is working fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.92479, 4.469833),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.latLngCoordinates.Length; i++) {
            addMarker(51.918769, 4.480616);
        }

        function addMarker(x, y) {
            var location = new google.maps.LatLng(x, y);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
            });
        }

    } google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

If I use:

```
addMarker(@Model.latLngCoordinates[1])
```

Or any other value up to 97 it works..

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(i)` if you add that to your for loop in the code that goes wrong?

Comment: also you may want to try `console.log(typeof i)` to make sure `i` is a number and not a string.

Comment: console.log(i) goes from 0 to 97 so that is correct. consolelog(typeof i) is number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're messing JavaScript with C#. This is a common mistake on Razor views.

Your `for` loop is JavaScript, so `i` is a variable of JavaScript. Your `latLngCoordinates` array is from C#, so they don't have direct relations.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.latLngCoordinates.Length; i++) {
    Html.Raw("addMarker(" + Model.latLngCoordinates[i] + "); ");
}
```

This make your `for` statement a C# code. So now, the `i` has relation with your Model's array. It will print many `addMarker` function as you got on `latLngCoordinates` length.

Comment: Use `@` to input codes within the html output like `@variable` or an entire block `@{ /* Some C# code */ }` or a statement `@if`, `@for`, `@foreach` etc... I came from PHP and I'm new to this engine and do like it, really.